# Unit testing html label

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a label that is populated through angular data binding:

```
<label class="my-heading">{{myBinding}}</label>
```

returns:

```
<label class="my-heading">Some Value</label>
```

How can i write a unit test to confirm the value within the `label` i.e `Some Value` if i mock the binding?

Comment: You need to use [Protractor to test that](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - unfortunately i can only use Jasmine

Comment: You're not going to be able to test that with Jasmine. That's HTML not JavaScript. Jasmine is not built to test the outcome of HTML.

Comment: If it's AngularJS then it can be tested